# стили css работают некорректно

Tags: html, css

почему стили в vs code работают лишь тогда, когда установлен плагин live-server?

Comment: Live-server лишь убирает необходимость постоянно перезагружать страницу, влиять на работоспособность браузерного интерпретатора он никак не может, собственно как и другие плагины.

Comment: тогда почему мой код работает при включении сервера, но при отключении - не работает?

Answer (score 1):

дело было в лишнем слеше при подключении стилей. закрыто.